How Could System.Text.Json Affect IActionResult HttpGet Calls, Resulting In Unsent Data?
I am currently updating our project from Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json. However, a strange error is occurring with this. There is a certain nullable property in one of our models which, while working fine on the backend, seems to disappear when serialized and transferred to the front end.
Using .net 6, and IncludeFields is true (though it shouldn't matter since this is a property). The property is a nullable integer.
What could be causing this to occur?

Your question is not answerable without more detail because there are many differences between Json.NET and System.Text.Json, see Migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json.  We will need to see a [mcve] to give you a definitive answer, as indicated in [ask].

One difference that can come up: System.Text.Json serializes only the properties of the declared references to an object, while Json.NET serializes all the properties of the concrete type of the instance (unless declared as object in which case all properties are serialized).  This comes up in situations where polymorphism is used: System.Text.Json will only serialize the properties of the declared base type.  See e.g. Why does System.Text Json Serialiser not serialise this generic property but Json.NET does?.

Did you set JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull somewhere?
